# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to start a react project with redux, but I am getting

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
----
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

The above error occurred in the  component:
in Provider (created by App)
in ErrorBoundary (created by App)
in App

**Package.json**

```
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "img-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jsdom": "10.1.0",
    "mocha": "3.3.0",
    "mocha-image-compiler": "1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    ...
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render () {
        // console.log('This is app.js inside render');
        return (
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Routes />
                </Provider>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Please help

Comment: Sorry to forgot, Its added in the last of my post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your react-dom to higher than 16.8.0